# How to add margin-top to Responsive Multi-Level Menu and not effect navigation animation?

Tags: css, css-animations

**Demo**

http://tympanus.net/Development/ResponsiveMultiLevelMenu/index2.html

After clicking on the hamburger menu icon, the menu displays.

This is the original CSS for the menu:

```
.dl-menuwrapper .dl-menu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

**Desired Behaviour**

I want to move the menu down from `margin-top: 5px` to `margin-top: 34px`, ie:

`margin: 34px 0 5px 0px;`

**Actual Behaviour**

When I change this property in Firebug however, during the animation that occurs when navigating to a submenu, the menu bumps up to its original position, and then bumps back down when the animation is finished.

I want the menu to maintain its vertical position during the animation.

I've been watching the CSS changes in firebug and I still can't figure out how to enable this.

The menu seems to animate from:

**Submenu Closed State**

`<ul class="dl-menu dl-menuopen">`

**Submenu Open State**

`<ul class="dl-menu dl-menuopen dl-subview">`

In between these 2 states there is another class applied:

`<ul class="dl-menu dl-menuopen dl-animate-in-2">`

or:

`<ul class="dl-menu dl-menuopen dl-animate-out-2">`

**What I Tried**

The common class in all these states is `dl-menuopen`, so I tried:

```
.dl-menuopen {
  margin-top: 34px !important;
}
```

But still got the "bumping up" effect during the animation.

Then I tried adding:

```
.dl-animate-in-2, .dl-animate-out-2 {
  margin-top: 34px !important;
}
```

But the menu still gets nudged up a little.

I also tried:

```
.dl-animate-in-2, .dl-animate-out-2, .dl-menu {
  margin-top: 34px !important;
}
```

But the animation is still jittery.

How can I maintain `margin-top:34px` throughout the animation?

Comment: Is this what you want? http://i.imgur.com/cwmY7b9.gifv

Comment: `margin-top:34px` to be maintained during submenu navigation.

Comment: I can't access the entire style but you can try this. http://d.pr/i/1l08O, instead of using margin, try to increase the `top` value.

Comment: I tried the code `.dl-menuwrapper > .dl-submenu {position: absolute; width: 100%; top:70px; left:0; margin:0}` and it didn't seem to do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to work:

Was:

```
.dl-menuwrapper .dl-menu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 5px 0 0;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Changed to:

```
.dl-menuwrapper .dl-menu {
  backface-visibility: hidden;
  margin: 0px !important; /* change here */
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  position: absolute;
  transform: translateY(10px);
  width: 100%;
}
```

Was:

```
.dl-menuwrapper > .dl-submenu {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Changed to:

```
.dl-menuwrapper > .dl-submenu {
  left: 0;
  margin: 0;
  position: absolute;
  /*top: 50px;*/ /* change here */
  width: 100%;
}
```

And added `margin-bottom: 34px` to `.dl-menuwrapper button`.